# AWS Glue job failing with empty error log

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am trying to run multiple (16) queries in AWS Athena through an AWS Glue job. The first few queries (14) are running and giving an output. After the first 14 queries, the Glue job runs for about 20-25 minutes and then fails without giving any error log. Log is generated correctly for the first 14 queries. I have checked the query separately in Athena where it is running fine. What can possibly be the issue?

Comment: Are you using Glue Version 2.0?

Comment: @AchyutVyas No. Using 1.0

Comment: Can you share a sample code you are running in your glue job?